# Read The Docs build failing without errors?

Tags: python, read-the-docs

I recently started using [Read The Docs](http://rtfd.org) and everything has gone very smoothly. Today I tried building a development branch of my project on Read The Docs. The build failed. After a few hours of debugging I switched back to the *unchanged* master branch and tried building again. The build failed. I do not understand why or how the master branch bulit successfully yesterday, yet today its build fails.

Here's is the traceback I get on my Builds page:

```
Error

sphinx/conf.py.conf
```

This is followed by two commands, both of which appear to have succeeded. To debug this, I looked at other Read The Docs projects and I see many which built successfully for weeks, only to fail today with the same error. The interesting thing about this error is it provides no tangible source. Many other projects have `ImportError`s or other errors of a more concrete nature. If I'm not being clear about how vague this error is, here's an image of the page:

[image]

Both commands appear to have succeeded. I do not provide my own `conf.py`, nor do I provide a `conf.py.conf` (though I don't know what that file even is, despite my google-fu), nor have I **ever provided any configuration files**. I've always let Read The Docs automatically generate everything it needs.

My project built yesterday. I did not change source in any way. Today, it will not build. How can I fix this?

Comment: Usually, builds require more than those two commands.  For some reason, RTD stopped halfway through the build.  It would be helpful if you provided a link to the failed build, but it looks like it just mysteriously quit.  You can report a bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org) if you're sure it's not your fault.

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the path of the conf.py file (Admin -> Advanced settings):

[image]